# cx_Freeze exe wont start

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, exe, cx-freeze

I'm using cx_Freeze to turn a program I made into an executable. I was able to create the executable but when I try to run it, absolutely nothing happens. I thought it was the modules so I tried turning a simple "Hello World!" program into an executable and it still did not work even though it has no modules.

Here is my setup file which is supposed to turn the program into an executable:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

setup(name = 'Quick Type',
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'Typing bot',
      executables = [Executable('main.py')])
```

And here is the program that I am trying to convert:

```
import sys
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

print("Choose a website.\n\n 1.app.typrx.com \n 2.careerstep.com \n 3.goodtyping.com  ")
choice = int(input())


while True:
    try:
        if choice < 1 or choice > 3:
            print("choose between 1-3")
            choice = int(input())
        else:
            driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\aaron\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            if choice==1:
                driver.get("http://www.ultimatetypingchampionship.com/")
                submit=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='middle-section']/div[3]/a/img")
                submit.click()
                driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.COMMAND + 't')
                driver.get("http://app.typrx.com/#RacePlace:race")
                time.sleep(18)
                inputbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("cw-QuotePanel-textToTypePanel")
                wordsarray = inputbox.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
                li=[]
                for i in wordsarray:
                    li.append(i.text)
                writebox= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='GWTUI']/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/input")
                for i in li:
                    writebox.send_keys(i+" ")
                break


            elif choice==2:
                driver.get("http://www.careerstep.com/free-typing-test")
                inputbox = driver.find_element_by_class_name("text")
                wordsarray=str(inputbox.text).split()
                writebox= driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea")
                for i in wordsarray:
                    writebox.send_keys(i+" ")
                break


            elif choice==3:
                driver.get("http://www.goodtyping.com/test.php")
                inputbox = driver.find_element_by_id("clock")
                wordsarray=str(inputbox.text).split()
                writebox= driver.find_element_by_tag_name("textarea")
                for i in wordsarray:
                    writebox.send_keys(i+" ")
                break

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Don't press control+C")
        sys.exit(0)
    except:
        print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
        raise
```

Help would be appreciated.

EDIT:I fixed it. Turns out avast was secretly blocking all of my python scripts like pip and cx_Freeze. I had to add an exception to the scripts folder and it works now.

Comment: Where are both of the files saved and how are you running them??

Comment: They are both saved in the directory of my project which looks like this: C:\Users\aaron\PycharmProjects\Typer\build\exe.win-amd64-3.4\. I'm also running it just by clicking the exe.

Comment: Open the exe from cmd. Open command prompt in that folder by holding shift and left-click the folder then click open command prompt here or just change it manually. Once command prompt's directory is on the folder type the name of the exe followed by.exe it should run and tell you the errors. Paste the errors here then I will be ale to start helping.

Comment: When I run it in the cmd, absolutely nothing happens, no errors, just nothing. The cmd isn't really frozen but it won't let me exit. I know its not the program because I run it in the Pycharm compiler with no problems.

Comment: If absolutely nothing happens I don't know what to tell you sorry I'll have to try it myself when I get time.

Comment: I would appreciate it.

Comment: The fact that it has been 6 days and your still willing to check back at your question makes me really motivating me to want to find an answer.

Comment: I found the answer so it's ok.

Comment: You should post the answer to your question it will surely help others in the future. :)

Comment: There is an edit at the bottom of my original answer.

Comment: Thanks, Avast was blocking my executable which was created by cx_freeze as well. Disabling it fixed the problem.

Comment: could you elaborate a bit more on the solution?